# WhatsApp call on Genymotion Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, whatsapp, genymotion, phone-call

I've installed WhatsApp on a Genymotion 3.04 Android 9.0 vm on a linux mint machine, sending and receiving text works, however video calling and voice calling don't seem to work, i can see the person i'm calling and he can see me (in a video call) but can't hear him, even though he can hear me, the same is with a voice call (he can hear me but i cant hear him).
so does anyone have an answer?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WhatsApp calling works fine with the Android SDK Emulator.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).